# PHP Array from Form then display

Tags: php, arrays, forms

I'm trying to build something that will allow a user to input names into a form text field with commas to separate and when they push submit to then have it put into an array and open a page that lumps those people into groups of x (also selected by user).  I have the code built to do this with a hard coded static array.  But I'm pretty new to PHP Post and Get so not sure how to do that part.  Can someone please help?  This is what I have so far.

```
<div data-role="page" id="pg_teambuilder">
    <div data-role="header" class="center">
        <span>Team Builder</span>
    </div>
    <div data-role="tabs" id="tabs">
        <div data-role="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#input" data-ajax="false">Input Values</a></li>
                <li><a href="#random" data-ajax="false">Randomizer</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="input" class="ui-body-d ui-content">
            <form>
                <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
                    <li class="ui-field-contain">
                        <label for="csplayers">Players (Separate by commas):</label>
                        <textarea cols="40" rows="8" name="csplayers" id="csplayers"></textarea>
                    </li>
                    <li class="ui-body ui-body-b">
                        <fieldset class="ui-grid-a">
                            <div class="ui-block-a"><button type="submit" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-a">Cancel</button></div>
                            <div class="ui-block-b"><button type="submit" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-a">Submit</button></div>
                        </fieldset>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </form>
        </div>
<?php

$string = $_POST["csplayers"];
$players = explode(',', $string);
/*$players = array("Bob","Blake","Jake","Jourdan","Jason","Tate");*/
$team_size = 3;

shuffle($players);
$players_chunk = array_chunk($players,$team_size);

foreach($players_chunk as $ul) {
    echo "<div id='random' data-role='content'>
        <div style='text-align:center; font-size:22px; line-height:100%; font-weight:bold; word-wrap:break-word'>Team</div><br>";
    echo "<ul data-role='listview' data-inset='true'>";
    foreach($ul as $li) {
        echo "<li>$li</li>";
    }
    echo "</ul></div></div>";
}

?>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

(For more information about superglobals (e.g. `$_GET` and `$_POST`) see the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php)

```
<!-- normal form with method post-->
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="names">
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>

<div data-role="page" id="pg_teambuilder">
<div data-role="header" class="center">
    <span>Team Builder</span>
</div>
<?php

    //Check if user submitted the form
    if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
        //explode the names by commas
        $players = explode(",", $_POST["names"]);

        $team_size = 3;

        shuffle($players);
        $players_chunk = array_chunk($players,$team_size);

        foreach($players_chunk as $ul) {
            echo "<div data-role='content'>
                <div style='text-align:center; font-size:22px; line-height:100%; font-weight:bold; word-wrap:break-word'>Team</div><br>";
            echo "<ul data-role='listview'>";
            foreach($ul as $li) {
                echo "<li>$li</li>";
            }
            echo "</ul></div>";
        }

    }

?>
```

Comment: Thank you.  I didn't even think of the if(isset.  I appreciate the patience with my limited understanding at this time.  One follow-up question... the form code shows in the source code but it doesn't actually show on the UI page.  I added value="submit" as well but that wasn't it.  Any ideas?

Comment: @Utrolig What do you mean with *the form code shows in the source code but it doesn't actually show on the UI* Do you mean the html or php ? Also are we talking about the code in my answer or your updated code in your question?

Comment: Yes, excuse me.  The code you provided.  When I put it into my php page, the form code shows as you'd expect in the raw code but not on the regular browsing page.  Very odd.  This code is the only thing within the body.

Comment: @Utrolig *but not on the regular browsing page* So you mean that you don't see this code on the page: `<form action="" method="post">` ? You should see a text field and a submit button

Comment: Right.  I don't see anything but white space.

Comment: @Utrolig And you only have my code in your script? If not what else is in your script?

Comment: Must be something in my head section.  I emptied it out and now we're golden.  Sorry to bother.

Answer (score 1):

here's a simple example

```
<?php if(isset($_POST['submit']))
  {
  $string = $_POST['input']; //here $string = "Bob,Blake,Jake,Jourdan,Jason,Tate";
  $array = explode(',', $string);

  foreach ($array as $players) {
    echo $players."<br/>";
   }
}?>

<form action="" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="input">
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"> <!--if u submit form with names separated by commas like Bob,Blake,Jake,Jourdan,Jason,Tate -->
</form>
```

Output:

```
  Bob
  Blake
  Jake
  Jourdan
  Jason
  Tate
```

Comment: `//` Are php comments not html comments (html would be `<!-- comment -->`)

Comment: Thank you.  This simplified version did a lot for my understanding of POST.  I appreciate the patience with my limited understanding at this time.